# FolderBrowserDialog + string

Tags: c#, winforms

Через FDB человек выбирает расположение папки где лежит сама игра. Программа должна сложить путь корневой папки с моими прописанными путями

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();

    string url = "https://paragonproject.ru/dlc_files/clothes/clothes_1/dlc.rpf";
    string dlcGTAV_folder = @"C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\dlc.rpf";

    if (File.Exists(dlcGTAV_folder))
    {
        File.Delete(dlcGTAV_folder);
    }

    MessageBox.Show("Установка началась, ожидайте.");

    wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), @"C:\Users\Администратор\Desktop\dlc.rpf");

    
}
```

Вот код FDB

```
private void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Выберите корневую папку с GTA V");

    FolderBrowserDialog FBD = new FolderBrowserDialog
    {
        ShowNewFolderButton = false
    };
    if (FBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Выбрана папка: {FBD.SelectedPath}");

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К примеру, у вас есть относительный путь

```cs
string path = @"dlc_files\clothes";
```

Далее вы получаете корневую папку, не важно откуда

```cs
string root = @"C:\Games\GTAV";
```

Чтобы собрать путь воедино, можно использовать конкатенацию строк

```cs
// плохой код
string fullPath = root + @"\" + path;
```

Но с этим есть проблема, вы можете не угадать, есть ли бэкслеш `\` на стыке строк и или нужно его добавить. А может там два слеша и нужно убрать лишний. Вот чтобы об этом не думать, есть спецаильный метод класса `Path` - [Path.Combine](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.io.path.combine?view=net-5.0), он сам позаботится о том, чтобы собрать две или более частей пути в один правильно.

```cs
string fullPath = Path.Combine(root, path); // C:\Games\GTAV\dlc_files\clothes
```

---

Вынесите код загрузки в отдельный метод

```cs
private async Task DownloadAsync(string path)
{
    WebClient wc = new WebClient();

    string url = "https://paragonproject.ru/dlc_files/clothes/clothes_1/" + Path.GetFileName(path);

    if (File.Exists(path))
    {
        File.Delete(path);
    }

    await wc.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(url), path);
}
```

И вызовите его из обработчика

```cs
private async void pictureBox2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("Выберите корневую папку с GTA V");

    FolderBrowserDialog FBD = new FolderBrowserDialog
    {
        ShowNewFolderButton = false
    };
    if (FBD.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
    {
        MessageBox.Show($"Началась загрузка в папку: {FBD.SelectedPath}");
        await DownloadAsync(Path.Combine(FBD.SelectedPath, "dlc.rpf"));
        MessageBox.Show("Загрузка завершена");
    }
}
```

Кстати, отвыкайте использовать `MessageBox`, выводите статус в [StatusStrip](https://docs.microsoft.com/ru-ru/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.statusstrip?view=net-5.0) или просто в `Label`